# passing a value to second segment in uri codeignighter

Tags: php, codeigniter, segment

Normally in Codeigniter a url by default has two to three segments like this. http://www.yoursite.com/controller/function

My question is, can I replace that function segment for a value if my code is in the index part of the controller.

I have a controller for just user profiles and I'm trying to make that the simplest url possible, so it's easily sharable. For example I would like the url to be something like this http://www.mywebsite.com/author/zazvorniki instead of having to call a function like this. http://www.mywebsite.com/author/user/zazvorniki

Is this possible? Is there a setting I can change to make this possible?

Comment: maybe of help ... http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I was looking at that, but it seems that if you set a routing rule that it will affect all the url's instead of just one controller...am I reading that right? I'm kind of afraid I'm going to mess everything up...

Comment: it will only effect those urls that are prefixed with the controller slug (i.e. /author/)

Comment: ok, but if I do a rout like this $route['author'] = "author/"; how do I plug in the user's name to pull up the right profile?

Comment: Answer shows the route rule that should be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following route rule.

```
 $route['author/(:any)'] = "author/user/$1";
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being so dense, but this still isn't making any sense to me. When I follow the rule you posted I'm still getting back a 404 error page because it seems like it's still looking for a function where the username is.

Comment: just for a test change the rule to ` $route['authors/(:username)'] = "author/user/$1";` so it won't conflict with the existing author controller route

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, for some reason it didn't like the :username, but it accepted :any.

Comment: I'll change answer to reflect this